# multiple forms in one step, Django Wizard form

Tags: django, django-formwizard, django-2.2, multiple-forms

I am trying to create 2 Model Forms in on Step, one of them is Modelformset, does someone did this before, it will be very helpful.
I am using Django 2 in my project.
Thank you.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    main_image = models.ImageField('main_image', upload_to='main_images/', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)


class PostImages(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField('Foto', upload_to='post_images/', blank=True, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,related_name='myposts',on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)
```

my Forms.py

Here I am Trying to create two forms, first one is main_image and the other is formsetfield in one step. that works but i can not get the instance of my formset so i can not save it.

```
class step3Form(forms.ModelForm):
    main_image = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'custom-control'}), required=True, label=_('Hauptbild:'))
    formsetfield = modelformset_factory(PostImages, ImageForm, can_delete=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('main_image',)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(step3Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

what schuld I do here to get the instance of my Formset? in order to save it!

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SessionWizardView):
    instance = None
    form_list = [PostForm, PostFormSecondStep, step3Form, step4Form]
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'media'))

    def get_template_names(self):
        return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

    def get_form_instance(self, step):
        if self.instance is None:
            self.instance = Post()
        return self.instance

    def done(self, form_list, form_dict, **kwargs):
        form_data_dict = self.get_all_cleaned_data()
        result = {}
        self.instance.author = self.request.user.profile
        form_list[2].save()
        self.instance.save()
        form_data =  [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]
        return redirect('post_app:post_create_page')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

html

```
          <form method="post" id="msform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ wizard.management_form }}
            {% if wizard.form.forms %}
            {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
                          {{ form }}
                          {% endfor %}
                {% else %}
                {% if wizard.form.non_field_errors %}
                    <ul>
                      {% for error in wizard.form.non_field_errors %}
                      <li>{{ error }}</li>
                      {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                    {% endif %}
                    {{ wizard.form.main_image.label_tag }}
                    {{ wizard.form.main_image }}
                    {{ wizard.form.main_image.errors }}
                    {{ wizard.form.formsetfield.errors }}
                <div id="formset" data-formset-prefix="{{ wizard.form.formsetfield.prefix }}">
                  {{ wizard.form.formsetfield.management_form }}
                  <div data-formset-body>
                    {% for form in wizard.form.formsetfield %}
                    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                      {{ form.errors }}
                    <div data-formset-form>
                      {{ form }}
                      <span class="p-2"><a class="cursor-pointer" data-formset-delete-button><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a></span>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </div>
                  
                  <input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="Hinzufügen" data-formset-add>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
            <button type="submit" id="submit_btn" class="action-button" name="button">Weiter</button>
            {% if wizard.steps.prev %}
            <button name="wizard_goto_step" class="action-button" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">Erster Schritt</button>
            <button name="wizard_goto_step" id="back_btn" class="action-button" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">Zurück</button>
            {% endif %}
          </form>
```

Comment: Hi @Abdull welcome to the StackOverflow community. It will be great if you can provide with the context of your code so that we exactly know what problem you are facing?

Comment: Hi @UmarHayat thank you for your comment, i added my code

Answer (score 0):

try this in function based:

Forms.py

```
  class step3Form(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Post
            fields = ('main_image',)
```

view.py

```
from django.forms import modelformset_factory

def create(request):
    formset = modelformset_factory(
                    Post,
                    form=step3Form,
                    fields=('main_image'),
                    extra=1,
                    can_delete=True
                )
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = formset(request.POST, prefix='post')
       if form.is_valid()
          post = form.save(commit=False)
          for row in post:
              row.userID = request.user
              row.save()
          form.save()
    context['form']=formset(queryset=Post.objects.none(), prefix='post')
    return render(request, 'post/form.html',context=context)
```

Comment: Hi @Rahman
Thank you for your Comment.
I am using Django Form-Wizard, also it has to be a Class (SessionWizardView)
https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html